# Modify CSS style as per nested sibling dynamic class

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have below HTML structure that is obtained through react classes :

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="inner-container">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="side-left-bar"> .... </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS as below:

```
.back {
    position: fixed;
}

.inner-container {
    .side-left-bar {
        position: fixed;
    }
}

.inner-container.relative {
    .side-left-bar {
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Now, inner-container is a react class where on resize of window a container class as 'relative' is applied, that allows the scroll effect.

Problem is, when this relative class is dynamically added in inner-container , I want to remove the position fixed style of back class through css?

Comment: you can do it through jquery using removeClass function while adding the data

Comment: code is entirely through react classes and predefined architecture.. I have control over CSS only.... hence some CSS tweak could help....

Comment: Isn't it possible to change the HTML structure so that `.back` appears inside `.row` after `.inner-container`? It shouldn't affect the display in case where `.back` has fixed position and probably can easily be fixed if it doesn't (e.g. with `display:flex` + `order`), but you would be able to use CSS selectors like `.relative ~ .back` to target it.